# Neo4j - Many count nodes by property value in the same cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Let's a have a node `Reference` with a property `rating`. Supose we have 2 references in the database, 2 'Positive' and 1 'Negative'.

Cypher query to count **positive** references:

```
MATCH (positive:Reference{rating:'Positive'}) return count(positive)
```

Return 2, *OK*

Cypher query to count **negative** references:

```
MATCH (negative:Reference{rating:'Negative'}) return count(negative)
```

Return 1, *OK*

Cypher query to count positive and negative references at the same time. Basically, joining the two previous querys in a single one.

```
MATCH (positive:Reference{rating:'Positive'})
MATCH (negative:Reference{rating:'Negative'})
return count(positive) as positive, count(negative) as negative
```

I expected the values returned would be positive 2 and negative 1. However, both results are 2.

[image]

Am I missing something? Probably I'm wrong but I'd swear this worked in older versions of neo4j (now I'm using 3.3.2).

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember when you are doing back to back matches like this, when there is no relationship between the things you are looking up, you are getting the cross product of all elements of `positive` with all elements of `negative`. So in this case, since there are 2 positive responses and 1 negative, you have 2 x 1 = 2 rows total (the single negative node will be listed on each row). You can change your return to `RETURN positive, negative` and view this in the table results view to see this.

To get the results you want, you can either get the count of distinct nodes:

```
RETURN count(DISTINCT positive) as positive, count(DISTINCT negative) as negative
```

Or use the better approach of collecting immediately after the match, which should ultimately do less work:

```
MATCH (positive:Reference{rating:'Positive'})
WITH count(positive) as positive
MATCH (negative:Reference{rating:'Negative'})
RETURN positive, count(negative) as negative
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and well explained reply! It works like a charm!